# Can't prevent password entry Form from closing in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm very new to this site and coding in general so I apologize if this is something simple. 
I have a button on my main Form that, when clicked, opens a second Form that prompts for a password. I want to be able to check that the password is correct before closing the form, but if it's wrong, I want the form to stay open so the user can try again. This is what I started with:

```
    public partial class passwordEntry : Form
    {
        public passwordEntry()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            passBox.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        private void passwordAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string pass = passBox.Text;

            if (pass.Equals("notmyrealpassword"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You entered the correct password!");
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect password. Please try again.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Then, based on some searching around, I added "bool check = false;" before the main public call, "check = true;" to the success MessageBox, and this to the end:

```
    private void passEntry_FormClose(object sender FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!check)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

End result, Visual Studio won't let me compile it due to

> Error CS1003   Syntax error, ',' expected.

Help?

Comment: This is a rookie mistake, if you double clicked on the compile error VS would have shown you the line the problem was on. Then all you needed to do is give that line the missing "," it expected. Check out some basic debugging video's on youtube.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put "," between method parameters:

```
private void passEntry_FormClose(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) // here "," after "sender"
{
    if (!check)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. That did solve my compile error, but I still can't prevent the password entry form from closing on a wrong password.

Comment: debug your code and see the value of check variable, I think, the problem is in that, because your code to prevent closing is correct